Getting the sum of Counts in the same query
I am trying to get the sum of all the counts of this field.
SELECT FieldName, 
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) AS sum
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY FieldName

But when I add the SUM, I get this error:
"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery"
Surely there is a way to get the total count in its own field?

Usually, this may be counted by window function, where window - whole table.



id
fieldname




1
name1


2
name2


3
name1


4
name1


5
name3


6
name2


7
name1



SELECT FieldName, 
       COUNT(*) AS count,
       SUM(COUNT(*))over() AS sum
FROM test
GROUP BY FieldName




FieldName
count
sum




name1
4
7


name2
2
7


name3
1
7



fiddle

That works!  Thanks!
